# How to insert a line break into code surrounded by a <pre> tag

Tags: jquery, html, xml, pretty-print, pre

I have a block of XML sample code that is all on one line, inside a `<pre>` tag. I want to programmatically break it up into multiple lines and then add indentation.

The sample code is already formatted with HTML special characters replacing the left and right angle brackets for each tag.

I plan to manipulate the code using jQuery by loading as a jQuery object. But how can I go about entering a line break after each tag? Both `\n` and `<br>` end up printing as text, because, well, it's `<pre>`. I basically want to simulate what happens in an IDE when you enter a newline with the return key. Any thoughts?

UPDATE:
Using .html() and `\n` I got it to work, shown in this updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SPms3/17/

Comment: Are you printing the values with .text()? You should use .html() to print the tags correctly, not like text.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're currently using to insert the newlines programatically and to insert the code into your DOM? This will help us see where the problem lies.

Comment: `.html()`, `\n` and `\t` seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5WUCC/

Comment: @jackwanders thanks for the demo..  a combination of the suggestions here worked. I think the main problem was an improper use of .text().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those should print as text.  Use `jQuery.html`, not `jQuery.text`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting this data in a variable, make sure to wrap with " in stead of ' because /n will not render if wrapped with ' (single) quote marks.

If you are not doing it with javascript, physically press enter on your keyboard to render a line break...